# iOS Spritekit Scrolling Menu

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skaction, skscene

I am implementing a horizontal scrolling menu for a `SpriteKit` game and have become stuck as to how to go about this. My strategy was originally to add all of my menu items to the scene and just pan the camera horizontally according to swipes.

The problem with this is that the menu is revolving/circular (last item links to the first, etc) so even if I repeated the menu items infinitely, after swiping constantly one direction, I imagine a coordinate limit would be reached and the app would crash.

My next solution is to add one menu item in my camera view, one to the left, and one to the right. Then upon swiping the correct item would move into my camera view via `SKAction` and the original item would move away. I would then removechild the farthest node from the camera, and add the next item to the scene in the direction toward which I swiped. This way my x range (in points) would only be -displayWidth to displayWidth. The problem with this is that I would need to animate all of the menu items at the same time, and as they are separate nodes I have not seen a way to synchronize their animation.

Also I need to check the position of elements on the menu items and change their shaders when they reach the border of the screen. `SKActions` seem to block the `SKScene` update method so I am ideally trying to avoid `SKActions`.

Is there any viable strategy that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is only a menu, it is ok to be a little inefficient.

What you do is have your menu cloned 2 times (so you have a total of 3).  You place one of the clones to the left, and one to the right.

You then add all 3 of these into a parent SKNode. You should now have one SKNode with the 3 menu items in a long string. Make sure your anchor point is (0.5,0.5)

You then run the animation to pan left or right on the parent  SKNode, with the condition that whenever you pass the edge of your original main menu, you jump in the opposite direction the width of the menu.

So let's say our menu is 400 (-199,200) points wide,  and our screen is 300 points wide (-149,150). Once the parent point -200 (menu point 200 or right side of menu)  aligns with screen point -150, you move the parent point to 200 (so menu point is -200 or left side of menu).

Since you are moving the parent node,  all the clones will follow suit, and you only need to run 1 action.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand - just to clarify each menu item i create takes up the entire screen. All of my menu items are stored in a doubly linked list data structure which is also circular.


Are you suggesting that I put Node.previous on the left, current Node in the center, and Node.next to the right? Or that I put EVERY element of the linked list once on the left, once in the center, and once on the right? 


I do believe I understand the concept of adding everything to a SKNode and then using one SKAction to move it.

Comment: @slugz i dont know why you have a linked list, so no idea

Comment: This is a store menu I am trying to make. I created a linked list structure where the node.value is an object of my StoreItem class. Due to the fact that each store item takes up the entire screen size, and the user has to swipe to navigate among the items I chose to use a circular linked list so that upon swiping I can scene.addchild(node.next or node.previous) depending on the swipe direction and then bring it in to view via SKAction. I am trying to use this method of adding/removing from the scene as required to improve performance

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using UIKit to create such a menu instead of SpriteKit. `UICollectionView` should be good for such a task.

Comment: If you are going to claim to using other technologies, then you need to be more elaborate with your answers.  This answer does not actually help the user and should be a comment.